# Restore access to amplify app after aws-amplify-admin that performs the amplify operations accidentally deleted

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I accidentally deleted the user pool with the user that performs all the amplify operations. Named aws-amplify-admin, which I believe, created automatically once I have created the amplify app. When there is no user I can't access the app through the console nor through the cli.

How can I recover from this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling and re-enable the studio. This should recreate the amplify-backend-manger user pool with the aws-amplify-admin user.
[Like show in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWVh1.png)

Comment: Please consider adding the image into your answer instead of adding a link to an image. It saves people the need to click over to another website to see it and makes your answer more complete with the image inside the answer.

Comment: @liam unfortunately when I added the image to SO editor it was added as a link